# PC restarts/crashes randomly for unknown reasons

Tags: windows-10, hardware-failure, bsod, crash

My PC randomly restarts/crashes. It happens every day and I noticed that it is mostly after i finish my gaming session (sometimes there is no gaming involved and it still crashes). I normally do not get a bluescreen and if I get one (on rare ocassions) then it's only for about 0.5 seconds so i can't read the error code.

I do not remember when exactly it started but I'm pretty sure it was there from the begining (when i build my gaming-rig about 3 weeks ago). I remember that it started out with a BSOD saying there was a "WHEA Error". According to some websites, this could be triggered by overclocking. So I deactivated every OC in the Bios (no CPU Turbo/Boost and no xmp profile). After two days, my PC crashed again but from there on without a propper BSOD...

Im pretty sure it is a HW problem.

What I've tried so far:

1. Monitoring the temps (at the end of a 1h gaming session) --> The [M.2 SSD](https://www.samsung.com/ch/memory-storage/nvme-ssd/970-evo-nvme-m-2-ssd-1tb-mz-v7e1t0bw/#specs) (64 °C) and the RAM (55 °C) get quite hot but should still run without a problem according to the manufracturer GPU at around 72 °C and CPU around 75 °C
2. Run Memtest86 --> No error
3. Check eventviewer --> No error right before the crash. Only an error directly after the restart which tells me that the PC shut down unexpectedly followed by some more errors and critical errors (to me none of them seem to point out to a specific reason or hardware failure for the crash)
4. Change BIOS version --> Tried the [7C94v15](https://de.msi.com/Motherboard/support/MAG-B550M-MORTAR) and the [7C94v163(Beta version)](https://de.msi.com/Motherboard/support/MAG-B550M-MORTAR) but still no luck
5. Change GPU driver --> Tried the [WHQL (20.11.2)](https://www.amd.com/de/support/graphics/amd-radeon-6000-series/amd-radeon-6800-series/amd-radeon-rx-6800-xt) and the [non WHQL (21.3.1)](https://www.amd.com/de/support/graphics/amd-radeon-6000-series/amd-radeon-6800-series/amd-radeon-rx-6800-xt)

**My Hardware:**

- MOBO - MSI MAG b550m Mortar (no wifi) mATX
- CPU -  AMD Ryzen 7 5800X
- RAM - G.Skill Ripjaws V [F4-3600C16D-16GVK] 16GB Dual-Channel DDR4 @ 3600MHz (16-16-16-36)
- GPU - Asus TUF rx6800xt
- PSU - Seasonic Focus GX 750W (80 PLUS-Gold)
- Storage - Samsung 970 EVO (1000GB, M.2 2280) & old 1TB WD Green Seagate (from 2015)
- OS - Windows 10 Education 20H2 (10.0.19041 Build 19042)

Is there any dump (for example the %SystemRoot%\Minidump) or logfile which could indicate the cause of the problem?
I did not try a clean install of Windows because it costs me a lot of time to reinstall/setting up everything (especially installing Warzone...) and I only want to do that if there is no other option left.

Comment: Look in C:\windows\minidumps for the most current dump and look at it with Blue Screen View (Nirsoft)  .   A WHEA Error 0x124 is a fatal hardware error for example.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com//help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly enough this question is not linked to my account...
@John: There is only one dump available (from to weeks ago) and the bug check code is 0x124. The description tells me it is a "Platform specific hardware error driver" (translated from German).
[BSOD Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6I3x.png)

Comment: This code is a fatal hardware error.  You might consider taking the computer to a local repair shop.

Comment: I don't have a local repair shop, I build the PC by myself. Is there any way to indicate what HW is doing these problems?

Comment: You will have to exchange parts until you find the bad one

Comment: i appreciate the advice but I don't just have spare parts laying around which i could use... Is there no logfile or any tool/function in Windows, which could give me some more information than "fatal hardware error".

Comment: Windows Reliability history might give you a clue. Control Panel, Security and Maintenance, pull down Maintenance and look at Reliability History.

Comment: From the 15.03.2021 untill now all the errors were 141 but weirdly not all of them with sudden reboot/crash (i got one 141 error todays but no crash). On some days there are a ton of them (nine of the 141 Errors within 1 hour).
Before the 15.03.2021 there are a couple of 144 Errors.

I couldn't find any Microsoft website which declares these two codes.

Should i post some screenshots (with the Params etc.)

Comment: Error 0x141 is the video chip / card. That now narrows it down.